# Multi language Poll output

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am developing a multilingual site, where the front page outputs the poll block with the following code.

```
    $block = module_invoke('poll', 'block_view');
    print render($block['content']);
```

The output does not change when the language changes. How do I translate that output with the i18n module?

Comment: create another poll for the other language.

Comment: How can I withdraw because I bring in software and it prints in all languages ​​created last poll

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your comment. What do you mean by withdraw? and what software are you talking about.

Comment: code output 
$block = module_invoke('poll', 'block_view');
    print render($block['content']);
this is module output last poll for all language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following steps in order to achieve what you need:

1. Download `Poll aggregate` patch file from [here](http://drupal.org/files/1173130_i18n_poll_module_5.patch)
2. Apply the patch file the way you want. Good Drupal reference [here](http://drupal.org/patch/apply).
3. Goto Modules list page `admin/modules` and install/enable the following modules:

   - **Multilingual content module**
   - **Multilingual select module**
   - **Field Translation**
   - **Synchronize translations module**
   - **Poll aggregate**
4. Then goto Poll content type settings page `admin/structure/types/manage/poll` and enable Multilingual support by choosing **Enabled, with translation**
5. Create a new poll content with its options and select default language from the **Language** dropdown list and save the node.
6. Create translation Poll content for the same node by clicking on translate tab.
7. Replace default language content with the second language.

I hope this will solve your issue.